# JPA EntityManager updates object before transaction has finished?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a strange behaviour. I have an update method which loads an object and updates some attributes there. Inside this method I have to query for other objects which are important for update as well. This is how it looks like:

```
public GroceryListBo updateGroceryList(GroceryListBo groceryListBo, String userId, String accessId)
{
    // some code 

    TypedQuery<GroceryList> recipeQuery = entityManager.createNamedQuery("GroceryList.findByAccessId", GroceryList.class);
    recipeQuery.setParameter(ApplicationConstants.PARAM_ACCESS_ID, identifier);
    GroceryList groceryList = recipeQuery.getSingleResult();

    BoMapper.map(groceryListBo, groceryList);

    setIdentifiersForIngredients(groceryList, userId);

    return groceryListBo;
}

private void setIdentifiersForIngredients(GroceryList groceryList, String userId)
{
    //more code

    TypedQuery<Ingredient> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Ingredient.findAllCaseSensitiveByUserIdAndPrefix", Ingredient.class);
    query.setParameter(ApplicationConstants.PARAM_USER_ID, userId);
    query.setParameter("ingredient", adaptedIngredient.getIngredient());
    List<Ingredient> resultList = query.getResultList(); // <- causes updateGroceryList to persist groceryList!

    //more code
}
```

Inside this private method I make a SELECT on another table. I need this data to update `groceryList` attributes BEFORE it will be persisted, but the SELECT query itself causes `groceryList` to persist. What is going on here and how can I deny `query.getResultList();` from persisting the main object? I wonder why this happens since the transaction usually ends when the main method `updateGroceryList` ends.

Comment: That's expected (and actually required by the spec). If you don't want hibernate to update the object before you execute the query, don't modify the entity before executing the query. Imagine this scenario: 1. persist user with name 'foo', 2. query for users, 3. wtf! no user found in the returned list with name 'foo'.

Comment: @JBNizet Ok, you are right, it does not persist as long as I don't change the object. I could rewrite the method, but I wonder if there is another solution.

Comment: @Naros You are right. It's what I was asking.